# Metal kernel function is missing buffer binding to change with time?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I have developed an iOS metal camera app but to have an error:

`Compute Function(kernel_function): missing buffer binding at index 0 for timeDelta[0]`.

The kernel code is as below:

```
kernel void kernel_function(
         texture2d<float, access::sample> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
         texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
         const device float *timeDelta [[buffer(0)]],
         uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]],
         uint2 tpg [[threads_per_grid]])
{

    float time = timeDelta[0];
    .......
```

It seems that the problem is `timeDelta` to miss buffer binding.  If I remove `timeDelta[0]` and set

`float time = 1.0`

There is no error and the app can run smoothly. But the screen effect is a fixed picture not an animation. So the `timeDelta` is to let the effect to change with time to be a video. Is there anyone knowing how to apply time on kernel function or to bind timeDelta buffer in iOS Metal to solve the error?. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Ken Thomases for your answer and you help me a lot. I have solved the question by adding the code

`computeEncoder.setBytes(&timing, length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size, index: 0)`

And `timing` is a random float to change the bytes of computeEncoder everytime to create an animation as I like. Hope my question will help anyone who has the same question. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

In your app code, you haven't called `setBuffer()` or `setBytes()` with an index of 0 on the `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`. Your app is not supplying the shader with the buffer it needs.

By the way, you should use the `constant` address space for `timeDelta`, not `device`. Also, assuming there's only one value, don't use array syntax, use reference syntax. So:

```
     constant float &timeDelta [[buffer(0)]],
```

and just use `timeDelta` directly in the code. (No need for `[0]` or to declare a local copy, `time`.)